# Smarty seems to ignore addTemplateDir

Tags: zend-framework, smarty

I'm working in a Zend Framework based application (Shopware).

I add a template dir in my controller like this:

```
class Shopware_Controllers_Backend_Pricify extends Shopware_Controllers_Backend_ExtJs
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->View()->addTemplateDir(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../Views/backend/");
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

But somehow, smarty always looks in the (not existing) part of the controller action:

```
Unable to load template snippet 'backend/mycontroller/model/main.js' in 'snippet:string:{include file="backend/pricify/model/main.js"} in Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 128
```

The Controller works over loading via ext js, but I do not see that this is a problem. When I var_dump template directories, the correct dir is included. I debugged the code far into smarty, but never found the part, where the directories are checked.

I'm aware, that this may be a problem within the software stack, but since I do not know where to search, I ask here. If I need to post additional data, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found, that the problem was that shopware extends CamelCase to camel_case folders.